# How to solve for a variable in logarithms

Tags: logarithms

How do I solve this for $y$?

$$u= 1 - \exp\left\{-\left(\frac{y-\theta}{\alpha}\right)^\gamma\right\}.$$

If I take the $\log$ I end up with

$$\log(1-u) = -\left(\frac{y-\theta}{\alpha}\right)^\gamma.$$ I'm unclear on how to proceed further to solve the equation for $y$. I apologize for not using the correct math symbols.

Comment: Subtract $1$ from both sides and then multiply both sides by $-1$ to get an equation of the form $1 - u = e^{\mu}$, which *then* suggests taking a logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $\gamma > 0$. You have 
$$
\log(1-u) = -\left(\frac{y-\theta}{\alpha}\right)^\gamma
$$
Multiply by $-1$ (so that both sides are positive) and take the $1/\gamma$-th power on both sides to get
$$
(-\log(1-u))^{1/\gamma} = \frac{y-\theta}{\alpha}
$$
Now, rearranging (multiply both sides by $\alpha$, then add $\theta$), you get
$$
\alpha(-\log(1-u))^{1/\gamma} + \theta = y
$$
or equivalently
$$
y = \alpha\left(\log\frac{1}{1-u}\right)^{1/\gamma} + \theta 
$$

Note: all steps are fine and can be rewritten as equivalences as the function $x\geq 0\mapsto x^{1/\gamma}$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you! Taking the 1/gamma power was the missing link... Once again thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome -- glad this helps.